# Does Webpack tree shaking with dead code elimination work on node_modules?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, material-ui, uglifyjs, tree-shaking

Considering this `Webpack 3.8.1` config.

```
// common
module.exports = {
        context: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        entry: [
            'whatwg-fetch',
            './index'
        ],
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/assets'),
            publicPath: '/assets/',
            filename: 'main.js'
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(['build']),
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'style-loader'
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                }, {
                    loader: 'sass-loader'
                }],
            }, {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff2|woff)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 8192
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    };

//prod
module.exports = merge(common, {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }),
        new UglifyJSPlugin()
    ],
    devtool: 'none'
});
```

and this `Babel 6.26.0` config

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            ">1%"
          ]
        }
      }
    ], [
      "react"
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-export-extensions",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

I was expecting that tree shaking alongside with dead code elimination of `UglifyJS` should work in a way that enables me to write named imports from `index.es.js` modules, for example `Material-UI-Icons` and unused ones get removed from the bundle.

```
import {Menu} from 'material-ui-icons';
```

This library does indeed reexport ES6 modules defined in package.json as `"module": "index.es.js"`.

Yet my bundle size increased by 0.5MB after importing single icon. When I changed it to

```
import Menu from 'material-ui-icons/Menu;
```

bundle size got reduced again with only this icon imported.

Is there something wrong in my configuration, or do I missunderstand how tree shaking works and does not apply to this scenario?

Comment: For what it's worth, the documentation for the package you're using explicitly calls out that tree shaking **should** work with it: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/v1-beta/packages/material-ui-icons#examples

Comment: Are you measuring your bundle size in production mode or dev mode?

Comment: I am starting to believe that it does not work across my whole project after closer examination. Bundle size is meassured in production mode using posted configuration. When I disable minification, there are "unused harmony ..." comments in the bundle so I assume at least some part of this process works.

Comment: I'm not sure how Webpack 3 supports `module`. See http://2ality.com/2017/06/pkg-esnext.html . *module is restricted to what is currently supported by Node.js*. Try to import `material-ui-icons/index.es` and see what happens.

Comment: `import {Menu} from 'material-ui-icons/index.es';` increased bundle size back to + 0.5 MB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after some additional digging, I found the cause / temporary solution / solution. Basically, because `ES Modules` can have side-effects, `Webpack` nor `UglifyJS` can safely (per specification) remove unused re-exports typically found in `index.es.js` or similar `"module"` entry point.

For now, there are some ways around it. Either you can manually import only necessary modules, or you can use [babel-plugin-direct-import](https://github.com/umidbekkarimov/babel-plugin-direct-import).

Good news is that `Webpack 4` adds [support for pure modules](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/5435/files) thru the `side-effects` flag. When library author marks it as pure, tree shaking and minification will work as expected. I also recommend to read [this nice summary](https://medium.com/dailyjs/es6-modules-node-js-and-the-michael-jackson-solution-828dc244b8b) about ESM specification support in NodeJS.

For now I would recommend to manually work thru your bundle using [this wonderfull visualizer](https://chrisbateman.github.io/webpack-visualizer/) and decide how to handle each large dependency on its own.